When I subscribe to a Kafka topic, it takes too long until I get first result. Afterwards the consuming cycle is normal. What could be the problem?
I am using following simple code (based on confluent Kafka) to connect and subscribe to a Kafka topic. After I call this method, it takes up to 5-10 seconds until I get the consume result. The server where my code runs, and the kafka server are both local servers in our factory. There is no high traffic that could cause this delay.
I have measured the times at 1) Timestamp-1 2) Timestamp-2  3) Timestamp-3.
The time difference between Timestamp-1 and Timestamp-2 is always under 300ms. But the time difference between Timestamp-2 and Timestamp-3 is at least 5 seconds and sometimes up to 10 seconds.
Once the subscription is done, the loop cycle time is under 100 ms.
The message I am consuming from the topic is quite lightweight (< 1KB).
What could cause this unexpected delay, and where should I search fro the problem? Is there anything that I can improve in the configuration setting?
Additional info: I have not mentioned in the code, but I close the subscription always with .close before I leave my application.
 public async Task Read_Status_from_Kafka()
 {
    // Timestamp-1*******************
    config = new ConsumerConfig()
    {
       BootstrapServers = "ServerAdress1,ServerAdress2,ServerAdress3",
       GroupId = "foo",
       AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
       SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
       SslCaLocation = "C:\\Cert\\Kafka\\xxx.pem",
       SslCertificateLocation = "C:\\Cert\\Kafka\\yyy.pem",
       SslKeyLocation = "C:\\Cert\\Kafka\\zzz.key.pem",
       SslKeyPassword = "password",
       EnableAutoCommit = false,           
     };
     using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
     {                
       c.Subscribe("my_Kafka_Topic");

       // Timestamp-2********************           

       CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       while (true)
       {
         try
         {
           var consume_result = c.Consume(cts.Token)                                                         
           // Timestamp-3*******************
           // code for processing consume result.                 
         }
         catch (ConsumeException e)
         {                           
           //Error handling         
         }              
           
        }

     }
  }


What's your conf-kafka version?

@TheNomad  Its 2.3.0

Seems like a known bug and according to the discussions it might have been fixed after v1.6, but the issue thread itself still has some traffic. The workaround there is a compromise by modifying the refresh interval (which I don't recommend, considering the trade-off is long term, compared to just the first message. There is another explanation here regarding its caching inner workings which might also contribute to it. But I'd recommend to post on the confluent-kafka-dotnet
github.

@TheNomad  I thought the question was about consumer behavior and your response was about producer behavior.  Am I missing something?
